# Getting actual SelectionStart position in RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I tried a started a project in MS Access with VBA and hit a road block, and wanted to see if it was possible with VB.net (I haven't started with the language yet):

With html text in a RichTextBox, I need to be able to take a user's selection within the text box and determine the text start location in the html source. When I used SelStart in VBA, it reports the location of the selection based on the formatted on screen display, but it doesn't account for the HTML tags. Is there a way to get the plain text position in the RichTextBox using VB.net?

Comment: WinForms or WPF or ???

Comment: I was thinking WinForms

Comment: If you were thinking WinForms then you should have tagged the question WinForms. We can't read minds so just thinking something isn't enough.

Comment: A `RichTextBox` is for displaying RTF text, not HTML. If you load HTML into a `RichTextBox` then the HTML source will be displayed. It will not be rendered like in a browser. As such, what's displayed on screen will include the HTML tags so the `SelectionStart` will take the HTML tags into account. If you have applied RTF formatting, it will not take that into account.